# Grafana not visualising logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, grafana

I have installed elasticsrarch and logstash and Grafana to visualise system syslogs.
Everything was working just fine, until yesterday at 7am when Grafana stopped refreshing and visualising any sort of syslogs in the browser. when I head to logstash terminal, I can see that I have syslogs coming in but in the terminal, but Grafana does not display them.

Did anyone faced this issue previously?

EDIT:
this is my logstash.conf

```
input {
  syslog {
    port => 3014
    codec => cef
    syslog_field => "syslog"
    grok_pattern => "<%{POSINT:priority}>%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}"
 }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
     hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
         index => "logstash_index"
 }
}
```

I do have a general question. Is there a way how to make my Grafana dashboard refresh every 1sec or even less, because to see the new data log, I have to manually refresh the dashboard.

Comment: Do you have any update on the ingestion side? Any update related with clients?

Comment: @hkulekci I did solved the problem. Was something wrong with my grok pattern. I will update my topic with the logstash.conf and you might help me please to understand why on my logs I have _grokparsefailure please.

Comment: @NaydenVan - glad you found the solution. Would you mind writing it up as an answer to maybe help others with similar problems in the future?

Answer (score 0):

On my first logstash.conf configuration I used this code to filter my data.

```
input {
  udp {
    port => my-port
    type => syslog
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

But as I am receiving all kind of data from logstash to elastic search, this might have created an issue during the parse and the filtering, forcing Grafana not being able to retrieve those data (even if I was still able to process them in the terminal).. changing the logstash.conf to this:

```
input {
  syslog {
    port => my-port
    codec => cef
    syslog_field => "syslog"
    grok_pattern => "<%{POSINT:priority}>%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}"
 }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
     hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
         index => "logstash_index"
 }
}
```

it solved my problem and now I am able to see all the data.